# How to use View Holder when having different rows in a ListView

Tags: android, listview

Usually an Adapter will have this to optimize the performance of the listview:

```
 @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + convertView);
            ViewHolder holder = null;
            if (convertView == null) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item1, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.textView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.textView.setText(mData.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
```

and view holder is:

```
public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
}
```

But what if i have different type of rows, like 1 with an ImabeView, 1 with a CheckBox, 1 with EditText

1st thing will be:

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {

    return 3;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

         //if something
         return 0
         //if something else
         return 1
         //if something different
         return 2
}
```

and in getView();

```
getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    //if convetView == null, getItemViewType(position) and depending on the type inflate respective layout
    convertView.setTag(holder);
   //else
    holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
}
```

But what about the ViewHolders, should i have 3 Different ViewHolders and depending on the type........setTag for respective Holder?

I could find any example for something like this. Actually i haven't seen anu ListView using more than 1 ViewHolder.

Am i doing it the right way??

Thank You

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is nothing stopping you from declaring all possible views from all of `ListView`'s layouts in a single `ViewHolder` class(so the `ViewHolder` will hold a reference to an `ImageView`, `CheckBox` and `EditText` from your example).

In the `getView` method when the `convertView` is `null` you will set the views in the `ViewHolder` only for that type of row, all other view references in the `ViewHolder` will be `null`. When it's time to use the views from the `ViewHolder` just see with which type of row your working and only get the views from the `ViewHolder` that belong to that row.

You could also use three `ViewHolder` classes for each type of row(and set them for each particular row when you inflate it), but I think the first versions is nicer. In the end you could go either way as long as you properly implement the multiple row types mechanism.

Comment: Sorry, but i just gave as an example ImageView,CheckBox,EditText. But actually i have 6 different rows, and every such row has 2-3 TextViews, 1-2 ImageViews, 1-2 buttons and very importantly they are arranged differently.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc The view arrangement doesn't matter. Also you don't have to actually add all the views from each of the types of row, if you have a `TextView` in the first row type and you also have another `TextView` in the second row type you don't add 2 `TextViews` references, you only add one reference in the ViewHolder as you could reuse that across layouts. You just need to have the maximum number of views that could be found in one of the row types(if you have maximum 4 `TextViews` in a row type then you would need 4 `TextView` references in teh `ViewHolder`).

Comment: fine. I thought You want me to have a single layout with all the possible views and hide/show depending on the type. hence asked about arrangement. So i will have a Union of all the views in the 6 different layouts in a single ViewHolder, right?

Comment: I have a doubt. Will android automatically give the correct convertView depending on the position, so that i can directly use it, if its not null or should i check the id or anything like that to make sure i got the correct convertView among the 6??

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Yes, the `ListView` will offer a non-null `convertView` of the correct type if it has recycled one. I've made a little sample with three types of rows and one ViewHolder, it should help you understand how to do this. You can find the sample here https://gist.github.com/4001523 .

Comment: @Archie.bpgc I think I missed something in your code.

How can the system guess which type of view you'll want to use for a specific position ? How can he know that for position 12 he has to use the recycle view that he used for position 4 or 8 and not from other lines ?

Comment: @CedricSoubrie `getItemViewType(position)` will tell you which view to be used. Lets say you have a data set in the adapter in which there is a type having 3 values **small, medium, big** in `getView()` you have the position and you will pass that to `getItemViewType(position)` and get the type from the data set. Now depending on that type, you will have to inflate the appropriate view in `getView()`. For better understanding please go through the link provided by Luksprong in his last comment.

Comment: @Archie.bpgc Ok, I get it now : getItemViewType(position) is a function from the BaseAdapter class. That's the thing I was missing. Nice pattern by Google !

Answer (score 1):

**-** I believe its **not** 3 `rows`, but a **Single** `row` with 3 **different components**.

**-** Single `holder class` with **3 different components** is what you need.

**See this example in the link below:**

http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Answer (score 0):

I second Kumar Vivek Mitra.
You need to have 1 row containing all the 3 views on below the other.
If however you want different rows then try this:

```
- create a custom row and put all the 3 views in it.
- set the visibility of all these views to GONE
- get the reference of all three views in ViewHolder.
- when setting the list, change the visibility of those views which you want to show to VISIBLE.
```

Comment: This is really bad, because you have too many Views per item even if they are set to GONE.